# Hibernate cannot parse connection String

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mysql-connector

According to Mysql documentation, this connection string from xml configuration file is correct:

> ```
> <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql:///database?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true</property>
> ```

And Mysql Connector/J parses the query parameters correctly.

However same connection string fails to be parsed correctly when Hibernate configures StandardServiceRegistryBuilder as the parser expects that that "&" is a start of an entity name. I found another suggestion to replace "&" with "&amp;" but this doesn't work either.

So what is the correct way of providing more than 1 parameter in hibernate xml configuration file? I'm using Mysql 8, Connector 8.0.13, Java 11 and Hibernate 5.3.7.

Comment: Could you post the error you get when you use the '&amp;' variant?

Comment: With the &amp;' connection string cannot be parsed in Connector/J. When getting query properties,you end up with amp key with no value.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it worked to me using `&amp;` to concatenate parameters:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/pbdatabase?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you try below?

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql:///database?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is same problem "The reference to entity "allowPublicKeyRetrieval" must end with the ';' delimiter."

Comment: How about `<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql:///database?useSSL=false&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" />` ?